# Using Jackson to serialize a Guava Optional<Integer> as a string

Tags: java, json, jackson, guava, option-type

I have a value object with an `Optional<Integer>` field. **I want it to look like a string when it's serialized**, but the `Optional` part is getting in the way.

I have the following class:

```
public class Person {
    private com.google.common.base.Optional<Integer> age;
    public com.google.common.base.Optional<Integer> getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = com.google.common.base.Optional.fromNullable(age);
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
@Test
public void testPerson() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new GuavaModule());
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setAge(1);
    String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person);
    assertEquals(jsonString, "{\"age\":\"1\"}");
}
```

It's failing with this output:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [{"age":"1"}] but found [{"age":1}]

I have tried adding a `@JsonSerialize` annotation to the property, like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
private com.google.common.base.Optional<Integer> age;
```

But then the test fails like this:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [{"age":"1"}] but found [{"age":"Optional.of(1)"}]

I've been looking around in `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.ser.GuavaOptionalSerializer` but I can't seem to figure out how to use it correctly, if even if it's meant to be used this way.

What can I do to get this test working?

P.S. If it were up to me, I would remove the Optional altogether, but that's not an option.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with `GuavaOptionalSerializer`, but I don't know how to set it properly using the annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own simple serializer:

```
public class OptionalStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Optional<Object>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Optional<Object> value, JsonGenerator gen,
            SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value.isPresent() ? value.get().toString() : null);
    }
}
```

This is how I specified it:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = OptionalStringSerializer.class)
private com.google.common.base.Optional<Integer> age;
```

Comment: An alternative since it seems strange to my eyes to use a ternary on an Optional : writeString(value.map(Object::toString).orElse(null))

Comment: The `map()` method is not available in Guava.

Comment: Ah, had in head JDK's optional... I think you could achieve same result using `Optional#transform` and `Optional.orNull`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Yes, but it's more verbose that way.